# Unable to remove blank space in simple HTML webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am unable to remove space between green and red lines. I've tried everything, still cannot do it. Please, someone help!

**Please, do anything, but please remove space between green and red lines**

```html
<html>

<head>
<!-- CSS --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.9.0/themes/prism-coy.css" />

<!-- JS --> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.9.0/prism.min.js"></script>

<style>
pre{margin:0px;border:2px solid red;}
pre::before,pre::after,code::before,code::after{height:0!important;}
pre[class*="language-"]:before, pre[class*="language-"]:after{height:0px!important;display:inline-block;}
code{border-bottom:2px solid green;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<pre class="brush: html line-numbers  language-html">
<code ="language-html">&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
Hi, my name is Peter Martin. 
This is my first program in HTML.
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;</code>
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem isn't in your CSS, it's the new line after you close the 
 `</code>` part. If you remove it, the space will disappear.
This happens because text in a pre element is displayed in a fixed-width font, and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.

```html
<html>

<head>
<!-- CSS --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.9.0/themes/prism-coy.css" />

<!-- JS --> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.9.0/prism.min.js"></script>

<style>
pre{margin:0px;border:2px solid red;}
pre::before,pre::after,code::before,code::after{height:0!important;}
pre[class*="language-"]:before, pre[class*="language-"]:after{height:0px!important;display:inline-block;}
code{border-bottom:2px solid green;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<pre class="brush: html line-numbers  language-html">
<code ="language-html">&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
Hi, my name is Peter Martin. 
This is my first program in HTML.
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;</code></pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The space is caused by the `</code>` & `</pre>` tags if you remove the space from tags like this it should work `</code></pre>`.

Your code is reading the html as it is. Html does not read spaces however in your code it is.