# why an extra line is produced?

Tags: html, css

I am wondering why this is producing an extra line.

I found from the another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754731/unable-to-remove-blank-space-in-simple-html-webpage#47754817). they says that it is not because of css  ,it is caused by HTML why?

I never seen anything like this.
why it isn't

*need explanation*

```html
<html>

<head>
<!-- CSS --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.9.0/themes/prism-coy.css" />

<!-- JS --> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.9.0/prism.min.js"></script>

<style>
pre{margin:0px;border:2px solid red;}
pre::before,pre::after,code::before,code::after{height:0!important;}
pre[class*="language-"]:before, pre[class*="language-"]:after{height:0px!important;display:inline-block;}
code{border-bottom:2px solid green;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<pre class="brush: html line-numbers  language-html">
<code ="language-html">&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
Hi, my name is Peter Martin. 
This is my first program in HTML.
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;</code>
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

`
 **how can i eliminate it by other ways?**

Comment: Your `:before & `:after` rules don't do anything.

Comment: The answer to the other question explains why, and it is because of the css applied to the pre by default. There is not much else to say. I want to close this question very badly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to remove blank space in simple HTML webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754731/unable-to-remove-blank-space-in-simple-html-webpage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The HTML `<pre>` element represents preformatted text which is to be presented **exactly as written in the HTML file**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

So because you have a line break between `</code>` and `</pre>`, it is literally rendering that.

If you don't want one then do `</code></pre>`.